# I am dealing with simpleimputer and got error "Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')" in python here's my code

Tags: python, arrays

**Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')**
First i import the dataset and then impute the things but it stucks!!!!

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd

    dataset = pd.read_csv('Data.csv')
    x = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
    y = dataset.iloc[:, 3].values

    from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

    imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy='mean')
    imputer = imputer.fit(x[:, 1:3])
    x[:, 1:3] = imputer.transform(x[:, 1:3])
```

Comment: What's the largest value in `Data.csv`? *Is* it too large for `float64`?

Comment: There is no large value in Data.csv for your clarification the most value is 45000.0000.

Answer (score 1):

**In SimpleImputer updated parameter**

```
imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy='mean')
```

We have to replace this as below

```
imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean')
```